# SVM giving exceptionally large value as classification results

Tags: svm

It is supposed to be really simple. I get some images, I extract features, I do BOVW (bag of visual 
words) and run SVM to train it to look for  a certain information in the image.

I am not doing any clustering at this point.

The training phase seems to go fine. However when I test it with an image, the prediction result is 
-1.08213e+09
where as it should be +/- 1.

I am using opencv svm. I am using C_SVC, linear SVM.
Why is this happening ? Has anyone seen such a thing happen before ?

Comment: Why would you use 'word' features on an image?

Comment: @bmargulies there you go